# mysqli insert into database from multiple checkbox with foreach

Tags: php, mysql

so i tried to get data from my database to checkbox and this is what i have tried :

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM siswa WHERE id_tingkatan='$idtingkatan'";
$result = $koneksi->query($query);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="murid[]" value="<?php echo $row['id_siswa']; ? >"><?php echo $row["nama_siswa"]; ?><br><br>
<?php } ?>
```

and save the value of checked checkbox into database, this is what i have tried :

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(!empty ($_POST['murid']))
  {
    $i= 0;
    foreach($_POST as $murid){  
    $kelas = $_POST['kelas'];
    $murid = $_POST['murid'][$i];
    $query = "INSERT INTO murid (id_kelas, id_siswa) VALUES ('$kelas', '$murid')";
    $q = mysqli_query($koneksi, $query) or die (mysqli_error($koneksi));
    $i++;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Pilih minimal 1 siswa');</script>";
    header('Location: ./kelas.php');
    }
  }
```

when i submit it does input to database but theres one extra row with id_siswa value as 0

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code. Have a read up on the use of prepared statments. Also be aware that with checkboxes, if a checkbox isn't checked then nothing gets sent for that checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inserts one record for each value in `$_POST`. However, `$_POST` contains all parameters sent (including `submit`), not just the checkbox array to be inserted. Iterate over the checkbox array `$_POST['murid']` instead.

Change

```
foreach($_POST as $murid) ...
```

To

```
foreach($_POST['murid'] as $murid) ...
```